# hide div depending on <select> option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, dropdown

I have form with a select dropdown (displaying a list of networks), a password field and a submit button.

It’s configured the dropdown to show a padlock on password protected networks and a no password image otherwise. This works fine.

What I’m looking to achieve is to hide the password field div if the user selects an open (no password required) network from the dropdown but I’ve not been able to get it to work.

The form:

```
 <form id=“network”>

 <select class="select1 long" id="wan-ssid" name="wan-ssid" ></select>

<div id=“showhidepassword”>
 <input id="wan-key" type="text" placeholder="Leave Blank to keep 
unchanged" name="wan-key"></div>


<div class="div_submit">
<input type="submit" id="submit_wan" class="button_submit" value="
<%Submit%>">
<div id="wan-message" class="errormsg"></div>

</form>
```

The script (images with e are the padlock images):
    …

```
stations=sortByKey(result.stations,"Quality");
        for(var i=0;i<stations.length;i++){
            var img;
            var has_password=true;
            if(stations[i].Encryption =="none") has_password=false;
            if(stations[i].Quality==100) img=(has_password?"/images/100e.png":"/images/100.png");
            else if(stations[i].Quality>=50) img=(has_password?"/images/75e.png":"/images/75.png");
            else if(stations[i].Quality>=25) img=(has_password?"/images/50e.png":"/images/50.png");
            else img=(has_password?"/images/25e.png":"/images/25.png");
            var has_password=false;
            if(stations[i].Encryption =="none");
            $(“#showhidepassword”).hide();
            else $(“#showhidepassword”).show();
```

Comment: You are using wrong double quote characters in your markup and in your script, and you forgot to close the div `div_submit`. Please fix your code first before we can help. Also, please include the function `sortByKey()` so we can see what it does. And what is `stations`?

Comment: It sounds like you are saying you already have logic that swaps the image if you need or don't need the password.  It's a simple thing to add the show hide to those if else {} code blocks.  I'm not sure where you are confused about this. Edit: You are aware that with if/else statements you can use `{}` so that multiple operations are executed for the conditional matches, yes?  Just like your for() has a {} around all the statement that should happen for each of the iterations.

Comment: You seem to just loop through your stations, at no point do you compare it with the selected one.  You've also declared `has_password` twice